# Shortcode from a plugin not working

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I am trying to understand how to create custom shortcodes in WordPress, so I am following the steps from one of the tutorials. So far I've created a plugin called *kadabra* and created a file in it called *kadabra-shortcodes.php*. its content is below:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Kadabra
 * Description: Custom shortcodes.
 * Text Domain: kadabra
 */

/**
 * Shortcodes
 */

// Test shortcode

function signOffText() {
    return 'Thank you so much for reading! And remember to subscribe to our RSS feed. ';
}
add_shortcode('signoff', 'signOffText');

?>
```

The plugin got activated successfully, then I went to create a new page and try the shortcode. I entered `[signoff]` and switched to the *Visual* tab, and got nothig but the same `[signoff]` caption.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: shortcodes only get rendered on the front end not in the admin

Comment: @AlexOlder, thanks. Unfortunately, I get the same `[signoff]` when I open the page. I am using one of the preinstalled themes.

Comment: Please try it in  kadabra.php

Comment: The code works fine for me. Make sure the php file containing this code is being included in the main plugin file. Also, only the main plugin file requires a plugin header (this part: `* Plugin Name: Kadabra` etc.).

Comment: @JacobPeattie, this is actually the only file. Should I rename it to kadabra.php as suggested by Pratik bhatt?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary. I'm pretty sure WordPress will load whichever file has the plugin header. Make sure the plugin is activated in Plugins in the Dashboard.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, ok seems like I have renamed the file and it got deactivated in the dashboard. My bad.